# Can a non https website access a https service?

Tags: http, https

I have a Web app (UI only) talking to a Webservice (lets say service x) and my service x is talking to another service (service y). Service y is a https only service from a vendor.

Question:
 - Can my web app be completely http only (app to x) ?
 - Can my service x connect to service y over http and still be not https enabled (x to y)?

Comment: I don't see why not.  Did you try?  Was there something preventing this from working?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you should probably evaluate why you want to do this. If service y is using HTTPS, they obviously feel their data is worth protecting, so by proxying it through a non-encrypted connection or loading it into an insecure page you are implicitly undermining their security.

Now, perhaps you're not actually sending that information over the wire but simply processing it on your server and sending a status result or something, then it might be ok, but the web is generally moving to https so you should probably consider "just doing it".

Comment: Sure its going to all HTTPS on actual production environment. This is my dev environment. Its all JSON data, this is just to make debugging easy for developers.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is just a protocol to connect a client and a server. If you have 3 clients: client A, B, and C:

- A can talk to B in any way, e.g. HTTPS
- B can talk to C in any way, e.g. FTP

Your app can be exposed via HTTP even if you talk to other services via HTTPS. The traffic from your visitors to your website will not be encrypted, the traffic from your website to the HTTPS service will be encrypted.